# Extracting elements of a list in Tcl

Tags: list, tcl

Consider I have a list in Tcl as follows :

a : { 12 34 1 3262 921029 232 0.2732}

How can I extract the three biggest elements of list a without sorting it?

Comment: this is not list, not dict, not ...

Comment: if a list `max([12, 34, 1, 3262])`

Comment: Please read [how to ask a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Keep a list of the three max values seen so far when iterating over the list.